# .NET Pipe deadlock or pipe broken

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, deadlock, named-pipes

I'm trying to do some logic according to this article, so many server pipes with many clients.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication?source=recommendations

But I'm achieving a deadlock when trying to do some stress test with a lot of clients. Server waits for write being completed and client also waits for its write being completed.

I don't close the pipe, because...

When I try to close the pipe after complete read, even with another instances created, I get `Pipe broken` exception on client - seems like the second client tries to connect to already closed pipe.

What approach is correct? Should pipe instance be closed after success operation? So how the second client should connect properly to not get `Pipe broken` error.

It's worth to say that I create a subpipes child pipes for scoped operations, but they work well and are properly disposed. The problem is with root pipe, so the one which many clients are simultaneously connected.

Also I use Protobuf for read/writes.

[image]

[image]

The client code:

```cs
  _pipeStream = new Lazy<Task<NamedPipeClientStream>>(CreateRootPipe);

  //...

  public async Task<NamedPipeClientStream> RequestPipeAsync(ClaimsIdentity forIdentity)
    {
        var message = new CreatePipeRequest()
        {
           //...
        };

        IMessageWriter writer = _writerFactory(await _pipeStream.Value);
        IMessageReader reader = _readerFactory(await _pipeStream.Value);

        await writer.WriteAsync(message);

        var response = await reader.ReadAsync<CreatePipeResponse>();

        return new NamedPipeClientStream(".", response.PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);
    }
```

```cs
await using NamedPipeClientStream pipe = await _pipeManager.RequestPipeAsync(...);

        await pipe.ConnectAsync();

        var request = new ParseExpressionRequest()
        {
           // ...
        };

        IMessageReader messageReader = _messageReaderFactory(pipe);
        IMessageWriter messageWriter = _messageWriterFactory(pipe);

        await messageWriter.WriteAsync(request);

        var response = await messageReader.ReadAsync<ParseExpressionResponse>();
```

The server code:

```cs
    Task.WaitAll(
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(ListenHandler))
            .ToArray());

    async Task ListenHandler()
    {
        await using var rootPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            options.Value.Name,
            PipeDirection.InOut,
            NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

        var messageReader = new MessageReader(logger, rootPipe);
        var messageWriter = new MessageWriter(rootPipe, logger);

        await rootPipe.WaitForConnectionAsync();
        
        while (true)
        {
  
            var request = await messageReader.ReadAsync<CreatePipeRequest>();

            string pipeName = GetPipeName(request.Username);

            var scopedPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                pipeName,
                PipeDirection.InOut);

            await messageWriter.WriteAsync(
                new CreatePipeResponse()
                {
                   // ...
                });

            Task.Factory.StartNew(ScopedPipeHandler, scopedPipe, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
                .ContinueWith(ScopePipeFailHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            
            rootPipe.Close(); // if not delete this line, the client gets pipe broken, if delete, then deadlock occurs in some stressful scenario
        }
```